# undefined reference to `Json::Value::<method>'

Tags: c++, json-lib

this is a following question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73049139/error-no-match-for-operator-operand-types-are-stdifstream-aka-stdbas?noredirect=1#comment129017981_73049139)

after re install `libjsoncpp-dev` and add `#include <jsoncpp/json/json.h>` i'm getting:

> undefined reference to `Json::Value::every_method'

Comment: There are two types of libraries: Header-only libraries, which have only header files that needs to be included into your source files (with the `#include` directive); And "normal" libraries, which have header files *and* one or more library files. If you have a "normal" library you need to *link* with the library files when you build. You seem to miss the linking part.

Comment: If I read the build-files correctly for the [project](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp), you need to link with either `jsoncpp_lib` or `jsoncpp_static`.

Comment: can you elaborate please @Someprogrammerdude